# Can free Jitterbit dataloader do an auto-relation like Dataloader.io?

Tags: data-loader, lookup, externalid

Until now I was a happy Datloader.io user as it allowed me on a Mac to insert from CSV and have this wonderful auto mapping feature where a Lookup or Master Detail relation can be pointed to an external Id field.

But...I just reached Dataloader.ios limits. No csv files bigger than 50 MB and with more than 40 MB the Dataloader.io reports an App crash.

The only offline dataloader for Mac that is a little bit more enhanced than Lexiloader seems to be Jitterbit's free Dataloader.

But I have a hard time figuring out how to resolve a lookup relationship with external id fields instead. Is that possible? And how?

Comment: The good old lexi-loader also can upsert with external ids.  Such a helpful one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get to what appears to be the end of the New Upsert Wizard, you will be prompted to "Map & Finish" on a button. Click that, and you'll see a screen where you complete your mapping (see pic below).

Any related objects that have available External Id fields will appear at the top of the right hand list of object fields with a "+" to expand. Expand that to get to your related External Ids.

[image: Mapping to related External Id Fields in Jitterbit]

From there drag the field on left to field on right (not tried the other way, but it might work), and you should be set.

Comment: I love Jitterbit.   I've demoed it to people who are shocked that it's free.

Comment: True. But last I checked the free offering was on a very old API version. Don't know if they have updated it recently.